# Cannot change screen orientation on VS2015 RC Apache Cordova Tools

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have just created a blank application from template using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise RC and when I change the screen orientation to portrait, the build fails on Android and I get the following error.

[aapt] C:\Users\HasanDogu\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3\platforms\android\ant-build\AndroidManifest.xml:6: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'Portrait').

It seems like the capitalization of the first letter in 'portrait' is not a valid entry for screenOrientation. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ask this already and got response from microsoft, open config.xml in view code mode and change Portrait to portrait.